# Displaying selected and count of number of items in a databse

Tags: php

I want to display the from selected in a database based on the number of applications jobs in this form
`job Name(number of applications)` for example **Accountant(4)**,**Driver(2)**
Here is the query of selecting from a database `$sql=mysql_query("SELECT  applications.*, jobs.jname FROM applications 
LEFT JOIN jobs  ON jobs.jobID = applications.jobID ");`

I have tried

```
$jobApplication_list="";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT  applications.*, jobs.jname FROM applications 
LEFT JOIN jobs  ON jobs.jobID = applications.jobID ");
$jobCount= mysql_num_rows($sql);//count the output amount
global $jobCount;
if($jobCount > 0){
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$jobname=$row["jname"];

$countt=(count($appID= $row["id"]));
$jobApplication_list .='
        <tr><td>'.$jobname.'('.$countt.')</td></tr> ';  

        }
}`
```

But im not getting the required results What I'm getting is this

***Accountant(1)
Programmers(1)
Programmers(1)***
Not that **I don't** want the **job name** e'g **programmer** to repeat i want job name to repeat i want the number to increase eg programmer(2)..(3)..on and on 
**Any Assistance will be appreciated**

Comment: Please give [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli) a read - it's deprecated, insecure and no longer exists in new versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(jobID), jobs.jname 
FROM jobs
GROUP BY jobs.jname
```

This query should return you a table with the job name and the number of rows with that job name in your table.

As tip I would tell you to get rid of `mysql` functions, they are deprecated, you'd better use `mysqli` or `PDO`, for further information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: there two tables not one. That is **jobs** and  **applications**  I think did'nt understand the assistance i needed.

Comment: I know there are two tables, and maybe I'm mistaken but why do you need the applications table in this case?

Comment: the application table stores the the applicantID, jobID and and the jobTable stores the available jobs.  I need now to format the applications in the format [link] (https://www.brightermonday.co.ke/search/jobs-in-accounting) in that link

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jobID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `salary` varchar(89) NOT NULL,
  `cletter` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=63 ;
`

Comment: jobs table CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `jobID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jname` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `jcategory` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `jdetails` text NOT NULL,
  `expiry_day` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `expiry_month` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `expiry_year` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jobID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `jname` (`jname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;

Comment: Edit your post aswell with your table structure to make it more clear

Comment: Well, as far as I have seen in that link you don't need the application table for anything. As I see it you should use the query I posted to find out the number of jobs with that name and then asign the field using the name.